# Ebyte E32 RF module configuration problem

Tags: rf, usb, stm32, uart, lora

I designed a PCB with an STM32G474RET6. I used an Ebyte E32-433T30S module. I searched on web and read the datasheet. So, I got some info:

- This Ebyte module needs to be configured before transmitting/receiving. The M1 and M0 pins work like a switch. If you want to configure you make these pins HIGH. After configuration, you make these pins LOW.

I thought it was a software issue and this module's SMD type, so I connected these two pins to STM32 GPIOs. Also, I didn't add a USB plug. I couldn't configure this module. I tried FTDI for RF settings application but it still doesn't work.

After I saw that problem, I wanted to ask you for a solution. I don't know how to configure this Ebyte module. Can you help me?

Schematic of E32-433T30S:

[image]

[image]

3D of PCB:

[image]

2D of PCB:
[image]

[image]

Comment: There’s Arduino drivers that you could use directly or adapt.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check AUX goes low indicating self-test on power on reset (POR).
2. Get UART working.
3. Ensure signals from Radio : Tx, Aux go to Vdd or add pull-up 4k

Comment: I didn't understand AUX part from your answer could you explain a bit larger

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short tutorial how to configuration (manually) these modules: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-3-L-ILPL-M&ab_channel=Moisen

You must send propers commands via UART for setting config. After that set M0, M1 pins. Consider use pull-up/down resistor if required.

[image]